# In swiper js, can you create a fixed height swiper, with the content of each slide scrollable?

Tags: ionic-framework, overflow, swiper.js

I am trying to incorporate swiperjs in my Ionic 7 project, but the slides are behaving weirdly.
The swiper is fixed height and each slide has a section with dynamic content, which can vary in height, so it must be scrollable.
If I set overflow-y to auto or scroll, the swiping action is ether glitchy or does not work anymore.

You can see the problem in my app on https://app.setlistory.com/

But here you have to register, create songs, add them to the setlist so the height exceeds the viewport (swiper is only in mobile view, you can resize the browser).

Am I missing something?